# event listener reference typescript functions

Tags: typescript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to add event listeners that references my local TypeScript functions.  Once I get my locations, I loop over my response adding an event for each marker.

```
        for (count = 0; count < this.historyList.length; count++) {
          let position = new google.maps.LatLng(this.historyList[count].latitude, 
              this.historyList[count].longitude)
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: position});
          
          marker.setMap(this.map);
          //now add an event to the marker.
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker) {
          return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(address);
            infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
            console.log(marker.getPosition().lng())
            this.map.setCenter(marker.getPosition() as google.maps.LatLng);
          }
        })(marker));
```

Now this works well for clicking on the marker, but I can't reference any of my typescript functions, so I tried adding a different listener:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
      this.highlightItem(3);  
    });
```

This works (using the =>) to allow me to access my local typescript, but now I won't get the specific marker that is being clicked, it will always reference the last in the loop.  How can I get the marker that has been clicked AND reference typescript methods?

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that you can refer to values in the scope around an anonymous function within it? You can just access the selected marker by using `marker` without an IIFE. Also, the difference you're seeing is due to the difference of the treatment of `this` in [function expressions vs. arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the Marker was always the last marker added.  

So I started poking at it, and found the issue.  its is because I created the marker variable outside of the loop, and then initialized once inside that was causing the issues.  Once I moved the let marker inside the loop, it worked as desired.  Thanks!